# React Native: How to parse an ics / ical file

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

What is the best way to parse an ical / ics file? I have it all in a string, but I cant find a package or library that is compatible with RN. All the general JS or Node ones throw errors about the FS package missing. I am reading it in from a URL and have it all in memory so I don't even need file system access.

Comment: What is the expected result of parsing the file?

Comment: I would like an array of events containing arrays of event titles and date/times

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question?

Comment: Well, right now I am manually looping over it, I was just expecting a nice library that has solved this problem already.

Comment: If you have developed code which provides expected result, what is the issue? Why is a library necessary?

Comment: Just thought there would be a better, cleaner way. There are many for node. I always like to offload work to a module rather than add a whole bunch of logic to my files if its already been solved somewhere else.

Comment: What is the definition of "better"?

Comment: I see your point. My core problem is solved. I have posted my code so that it could be helpful to someone else in the future. However, my question was really to determine if a module did or did not exist, and why some of the pure Node.js ones were failing, perhaps for my own curiosity and to save others in the future from spending a bunch of time researching and testing modules that ended up failing to solve the problem.

Comment: _"my question was really to determine if a module did or did not exist"_  At list of potential reasons for "close" vote, _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_. However, given _"I have posted my code so that it could be helpful to someone else in the future"_  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Why do you not create and publish the module using your own code?

Comment: Just for anyone reading this, @guest271314 has no clue what he is talking about and obviously not a lot of programming experience. You should never implement something yourself if you could use a library other than for learning purposes. (Of course, never is an exaggeration for the general case but for beginners and inexperienced programmers the answer is definitely never)

Answer (score 11):

Anyone looking for the answer to this question in 2019+, I've written an npm module to solve this problem! You can find it [here](https://github.com/Christop406/ical-parser)! (https://github.com/Christop406/ical-parser).

Or, if you're lazy, just run `npm i cal-parser` (**NOT** `ical-parser`).

You can use it like this:

```
const ical = require('cal-parser');

var parsedCal = ical.parseString(MY_ICAL_STRING);

console.log(parsedCal.calendarData); // for calendar metadata
console.log(parsedCal.events);       // for calendar events
```

Happy parsing!

Comment: if the same key is repeating in the `.ics`, it will not parse all. Instead, it will take the last key, otherwise the package is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to find any such module. Here is the basic code I used to solve this issue:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(
      "GET",
      "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics",
      true
    );
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        var type = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
        if (type.indexOf("text") !== 1) {
          var lines = request.responseText.split("\n");
          var events = {}
          var events_i = 0;
          for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if (lines[i].includes('DTSTART')) {
              var date = lines[i].split(":");
              events[events_i] = {date: date[1]};
            }
            else if (lines[i].includes('SUMMARY')) {
              var title = lines[i].split(":");
              events[events_i]["title"] = title[1];
            }
            else if (lines[i].includes('END:VEVENT')) {
              events_i++;
            }
          }
          console.log(events);
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Just as a note for people seeing this, this does not support recurring events and is exactly the reason why you should use a library rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Implementing a random blackbox library for every 20lines of vanllia javascript is also not the way to go.